# How To Replace Items in Second Array Using React Post Api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rest

I have a post Api in which I want to send the answers based on users input in an array like :
**userAnswer ["correct", "correct", "wrong", "notAttempted", "correct"]** and then replace the correct and wrong answers based on their index in the next section in a different array that is like this :

**{**
"answersArray": [
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted"
],
}

```
  const [arry, setArry] = useState([]);

  const nextQuestion = (examData) => {

    if (studentAnswered == examData[currentQuestion].correct) {
      setArry((prevState) => [...arry, "correct"]);
    } else if (studentAnswered == null) {
      setArry((prevState) => [...arry, "notAttempted"]);
    } else {
      setArry((prevState) => [...arry, "wrong"]);
    }

    setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
    setStudentAnswered(null);
  };
```

The **array** is a useState Function and **NextQuestion** is an onClick function it adds the selected answer to the array onClick or keeps the value null if no options are selected. **I was able to do most of the work. Now I just need to update the correct and wrong answers to the AnswersArray Above based on their indexes. Thanks **

> Edit :  the first array will store the option that the user selects. Lets say you have 20 questions and the user answers 5 questions. userAnswer ["correct", "correct", "wrong", "notAttempted", "correct"]. the correct and wrong answers need to be pushed into the second array above in which all of the indexes have "notAttempted" value stored. So my question is **how can I update the values in Array2 with the values in array1 which is userAnswer. The answersArray should look like this :**

**{**
"answersArray": [
"correct",
"correct",
"wrong",
"notAttempted",
"correct",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted",
"notAttempted"
],
}

The values in userAnswer will be pushed into answersArray based on the index number. I hope this make the question more clear now.

Comment: Is not clear what is the difference between the first and second array

Comment: _`userAnswer{"correct", "correct", "wrong", "notAttempted", "correct"}`_ <-- I'm afraid this is not an array. An array is like this: `userAnswer = ["correct", "correct", "wrong", "notAttempted", "correct"]`. It is enclosed within `[` square braces `]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the difference in array1 and 2 is that the second array has only "notAttempted" as values. I want to replace those with "correct" and "wrong" from the array1(userAnswer) based on the index. Like userAnswer has "correct" as the first value so I want to replace it in the answersArray which has "notAttempted" as the first value with "correct" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Array methods to replace any value in the array using an index.